# How to convert this snippet from Flow to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, flowtype, typescript-typings

I have a glitch in my migration from flow to TypeScript. I have this piece of code that I need to migrate. How can I convert it?

In Flow

```
export type IconType = $Keys<typeof Images.icons>
```

Is this how to convert it to TypeScript?

```
export type IconType = keyof typeof Images.icons
```

Comment: That looks about right, what issue are you having ?

Comment: I am trying to use it in my component. when I was using flow i used to use it like 

<Image
      source={Images.icons[type]}
    />
my props is   type: IconType
but would the same work in typescript?

Comment: The reason I ask is I am getting empty icons around the app

Comment: Without a minimal working sample it's hard to tell what your issue is. But this works as expected: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Images%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20icons%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delete%3A%20'delete.png'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edit%20%3A%20'edit.png'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20IconType%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20Images.icons%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20type%3A%20IconType%3B%0D%0Alet%20value%20%3D%20Images.icons%5Btype%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this how to convert it to TypeScript?

Yes.

The flow `$Keys` : https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys has same effect as TypeScript `keyof` : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

i.e both return a string union of key names.